# PHP Dropdown Box from SQL Join

Tags: php, sql

I want to do is have a dropdown box that will display the MealOption and when that is selected somehow find that products meal id?

This is my database layout
[image: This is my database layout]

Comment: yes it is possible..

Comment: @habibulhaq would you possibly have a link to an example? been looking a quiet a while and cant see any

Comment: wait I have a similiar kind of code. I will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
public function get_data()
{
   $mysqli= new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) or die("Couldn't    connect".mysqli_connect_error());
   $sql="select id,name from table";
   $result=$mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
      while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
      {
        echo "<option value=\"".$row["id"]."\"  selected>".$row["name"]."</option>";
      }
 }  
?>
<select name="abc" id="xyz">
<?php  get_data(); ?>
</select>
```

In the function connect the db and then run the query. in the while loop echo your rows like above so you can get your name and id from table. In the end in your html call this function.